# How does ~1024p get into my lager logs sometimes?

Tags: erlang, lager

I'm using lager in an erlang app, and I occasionally have log statements like the following:

`?log_error("failed to create reward instance: ~1024p", Reason)`

where Reason was returned from a previous function call. As I understand it ~1024p should be turned into whatever Reason is, so that even if Reason is an empty string I would expect

`failed to create reward instance: ""`

but sometimes I get

`failed to create reward instance: ~1024p`

I'm just wondering if anyone can explain this behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The macro definition of ?log_error is:

`-define(log_error(Message, Arguments),
        ?do_log_error(Message, Arguments)
       ).`

`-define(do_log_error(Message, Arguments),
        ?log(error, Message, Arguments)).`

`-define(log(Level, Message, Arguments), ok = lager:Level(Message, Arguments)).`

This means that `?log_debug("...", Reason)` calls `lager:error("...",Reason)` in the end. I don't see the function `error` in lager.erl. I'm guessing it must have to do with `-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).`. Unfortunately I don't know enough about parse transforms yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me definition of macro `log_error`?

Comment: Sorry. Added the definition of log_error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to your macro should always be a list, one for each formatting specifier in your format string, as that's what's required by the `lager` functions your macro calls:

```
?log_error("failed to create reward instance: ~1024p", [Reason])
```